# How to set scrollbar postion of RadCartesian chart to Right side in wpf telerik

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have a RadCartesian chart. I have Zoomed it and I want its poistion at extreme right on X-axis.

[image: Here I have zoomed the chart and I want to set the position of scroll bar to the extreme right]

Comment: show us your attempt !

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by setting

```
radchart.HorizontalZoomRangeStart = somevalue;
radchart.HorizontalZoomRangeEnd = somevalue;

For e.g.
radchart.HorizontalZoomRangeStart = .9;
radchart.HorizontalZoomRangeEnd = 1;
```